# STM32H743 + Linux + extra python modules

Tags: python, linux-kernel, stm32h743

I've followed [[this](https://elinux.org/STM32)] and I've obtained the xipImage @ linux-5.10.186/arch/arm/boot. The following are my doubts,

1. Why can't get zImage/uImage?
2. So with the resultant xipImage, how am I supposed to boot this resultant linux kernel into STM32H743?
3. Also how to incorporate external python modules in it, if possible?

Also, form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096527/linux-kernel-crashes-on-the-stm32h743i), the author @Mahyar has implemented this.

I've obtained the xipImage. Expecting Why I can't get zImage/uImage?

Comment: "this" contains many steps and descriptions for different tasks. So, what exact steps have you **actually** performed? Please, update the question post with that information.